# Use of the verb”complete” in the sentence

Tags: verbs

When  we send partial truckload of product it mostly costs too much. This is why we always try to send full truckload of product. In this case if I use the verb” complete” to describe this situation in the way below would it be correct ?

> We need to complete full truckload by buying a few amount of product because it can cost too high to deliver products in partial truckload.

( by the way I  also couldn’t be sure if use of “ in partial truckload “ is correct or not)

Answer (score -1):

## This is incorrect

1. In this sentence complete is not a verb, you're trying to use complete to describe the fullness of the truck, to do this you need completely instead. So you should use the phrase "completely fill the truckload" instead of "complete full truckload"
2. You just need an "s" in your other phrase "in partial truckloads"